# Creating and naming files with a while function

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

i'm trying to create files, one for each day of the year, and I was thinking I would use `while` or `for` for this. but it doesn't seem to work since I'm mixing numbers and letters.

```
def CreateFile():
    date = 101 
#this is supposed to be 0101 (first of januar, but since i can't start with a 0 this had to be the other option)

    while date <= 131:
        name = (date)+'.txt'
        date += 1
CreateFile()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate strings and integers:

```
name = date + '.txt' # TypeError
```

but you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to create the filename:

```
name = "{0}.txt".format(date)
```

Using `str.format` also allows you to force four digits, including the leading zero:

```
>>> "{0:04d}.txt".format(101)
'0101.txt'
```

*(see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more on formatting options).*

Finally, given that you know how many times you will loop, I would recommend a `for` loop with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) here, to avoid initialising and incrementing `date` manually:

```
for date in range(101, 132):
    name = "{0:04d}.txt".format(date)
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, that went fast. Canged it to what you said and now it works great. 

Thanks!